# How can i hide the download link of another server?

Tags: php

I sell video in my website. users must pay to have access to files (to download or stream them online)

**problem**: the video files are not on my main server! i store them on another server.(special server for download. i don't want to use the bandwidth of my main server) i don't want to provide the users with the direct link. (not to let them share the links with others...). how can i let them to download the files or stream the videos without giving them the direct links?

points:
- I can not have database(mysql) in my download server.
- i don't want to use the bandwidth of my main site. just checking payments and controlling user accounts.
- streaming is not so important. but i have to let them download the files.
- i have seen in woo commerce plugin(wordpress) which creates temporary download links even for remote server. i checked solutions for temp download link but all works for the same server not remote one....

Comment: You probably can't, if you're streaming from a server, the user can generally always check the network to see where it's streaming from.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I think this could happen is:

1. The public server must be able to establish an SSH (preferably) connection to the other server with appropriate permissions.
2. Upon successful request, create a random symlink pointing to the original file.
3. Store the symlink filename in a database, and save the user's IP as well - or some other unique identifier (or md5'd IP + User Agent - it's up to you).
4. If the request is valid (matches the record in the database), let him download the file. Otherwise redirect him to an error page.
5. Set up a cron to delete symlinks older than X hours.